# Spring Stream kafka Binder Test Custom Headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to figure out how to include custom headers in the Spring `Message<?>` used in Spring Cloud Stream with the Kafka Binder. My goal is to include some custom header data that would be added on in one producer (function) class, passed to kafka and then consumed by another class in a different service (with the customer header data).

I feel like I am missing something as I can seem to get it to work using the `TestChannelBinder` e.g.

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.function.Function;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class BaseStream implements Function<Message<String>, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(Message<String> transactionMessage) {
        log.debug("Converted Message: {} ", transactionMessage);
        return transactionMessage.getPayload();
    }

}
```

Test class with Test Binder:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.InputDestination;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.OutputDestination;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.TestChannelBinderConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;


@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:testStream.properties")
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
public class TestForStream {


    @Autowired
    InputDestination inputDestination;
    @Autowired
    OutputDestination outputDestination;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        inputDestination.send(MessageBuilder
                .withPayload("Test Payload")
                .setHeader("customHeader", "headerSpecificData")
                .build());
    }
}
```

testStream.properties

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=baseStream
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.baseStream-in-0.destination=test-in
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.baseStream-out-0.destination=test-out
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.baseStream-in-0.group=test-group-base
```

Log when running:

```
Converted Message: GenericMessage [payload=Test Payload, headers={id=5c6d1082-c084-0b25-4afc-b5d97bf537f9, customHeader=headerSpecificData, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1639398696800, target-protocol=kafka}]
```

Which is what I am looking to do. But when I try to test it for the kafka bider it seems to include the `Message<String>` object in the payload as a JSON string, which I thought would be parsed into the requested input of the function `BaseStream`.

Just wondering if someone could maybe see where i'm going wrong with my testing as I have tried various things to get this to work, and seeing as it works with a test binder I would assume it works for the Kafka Binder.

Test Class for Kafka Binder Test:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092"})
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:testStream.properties")
public class TestForStream {

    public static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    @Autowired
    public EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        sleep(5);//Included this as it takes some time to init>

        sendMessage("test-in", MessageBuilder
                .withPayload("Test Payload")
                .setHeader("customHeader", "headerSpecificData")
                .build());


    }

    public <T> ProducerFactory<String, T> createProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>(KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(broker));
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        //Is JsonSerializer correct for a message?
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs);
    }

    public <T> void sendMessage(String topic, T listObj) {
        try {
            KafkaTemplate<String, T> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(createProducerFactory());
            kafkaTemplate.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, listObj));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sleep(long time){
        try {
            latch.await(time, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Log of kafka binder test for message:

```
Converted Message: GenericMessage [payload={"payload":"Test Payload","headers":{"customHeader":"headerSpecificData","id":"d540a3ca-28db-b137-fc86-c25cc4b7eb8b","timestamp":1639399810476}}, headers={deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedTopic=test-in, target-protocol=kafka, kafka_offset=0, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@79580279, id=1cf2d382-df29-2672-4180-07da99e58244, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1639399810526, contentType=application/json, __TypeId__=[B@24c79350, kafka_groupId=test-group-base, timestamp=1639399810651}]
```

So here the message has been included in the payload and the kafka headers included in the headers as expected.

I have tried `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers` and `headerMode` to see if they would change anything but to no avail.

Edit:

Using springCloudVersion = 2020.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using:

```
public <T> void sendMessage(String topic, T listObj) {
    try {
        KafkaTemplate<String, T> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(createProducerFactory());
        kafkaTemplate.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, listObj));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To send the message which was putting the message as the value.

What I should've been using:

```
public void sendMessage(String topic, Message<?> listObj) {
    try {
        KafkaTemplate<String, Message<?>> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(createProducerFactory());
        kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic(topic);
        kafkaTemplate.send(listObj);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```